# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.saved_model' has no attribute 'loader'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use a model for OCR and I have this block of code which results in the error:
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.saved_model' has no attribute 'loader'" which I assume is due to using a TF version 1 construction that is not valid anymore in V2

```
def load_graph(self, modelFile):    
        graph = tf.Graph()
        # graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
Point of failure -> model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], './model')
        graph_def = model.graph_def
        
        with open(modelFile, "rb") as f:
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        
        with graph.as_default():
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
        
        return graph
```

I have changed the original construction from tf.Session() to tf.compat.v1.Session(), which leads us to this error.
What would be the equivalent for TF V2 that I can use in this case?

EDIT: Previously I had tried this variation which had the same error.

```
def load_graph(self, modelFile):
         
        graph = tf.Graph()
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
         
        with open(modelFile, "rb") as f:
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
         
        with graph.as_default():
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
         
        return graph
```

Comment: Can you try changing `tf.saved_model.loader.load` to `tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load`. You can [refer here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/saved_model#tensorflow_1_load_a_savedmodel_with_tfsaved_modelload) for more details.

Comment: @Kishore This has indeed worked, thank you. 
Now there is a new error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.saved_model' has no attribute 'tag_constants'" but it's likely there will be more further down the line, so then my new question is how can I efficiently look up the newer versions of methods, in order to "translate" the old TF1.15 methods into the latest TF2 ones?

Comment: [Migrate the SavedModel workflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/saved_model), will guide you to migrate Tf1 saved model to Tf2 compatible. Thanks!